# Reference request to the theory of the spectrum of unbounded linear operators: Proof for why the spectrum of the Laplacian is discrete on compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, laplacian

This question might already have been asked on this site and I have asked a similarish question before: [Reference request to the theory and examples of the spectrum of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on different compact manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4686455/820472) Unfortunately none of the posted questions and posted answers to my previous question have helped me with this: Which, if any, source contains a clear and rigorous treatment of the spectrums of unbounded linear operators? Moreover, precisely what is the argument for the discreteness of the spectrum of the Laplacian operator $\Delta = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d^2}{dx_i^2}$? Brief search on the quite dense book, "*Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, Analysis of Operators*" by Reed and Simons produces at least one result which shows that the resolvent of the Dirichlet Laplacian on bounded sets is compact. This might be close to what I am looking for (or imply it immediately), but I am really looking for a concise reference which I can verify that shows the discreteness of $\sigma(\Delta)$ when $\Delta$ is restricted on compact sets. But while we are at it, I wouldn't mind learning more about the spectrum of said operator(s) in general. Is it so that the book by Reed and Simon contains all that I need, but it just takes work to find the right results? Or is there some other reference I should take a look at?

Comment: I'm not sure that the resolvent is compact when restricted to any compact set (probably somebody may  clarify this).
In some cases it  is, for example when restricted to a compact domain (smooth manifold with smooth boundary) and considered as acting on Sobolev spaces $H_0$ (vanishing on the boundary).
I think in general in the compact case you might want to choose the function spaces where the operator is acting carefully so that you end up with a Fredholm operator. 
One of the ways to prove that the spectrum is discrete is by showing that the operator is self-adjoint and is Fredholm.